# Detecting an object and get the mean pixel value (BGR)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a picture of a leaf with a white paper as the background and I need to remove the noise (yellow dot) and get the pixel value (bgr) of the leaf.

I used green threshold to detect the leaf and masked it with the original image. I used cv2.mean to get the pixel value, but it counts all the pixel include the black area/background.

How to get the pixel value only for the leaf?
Here is the code I used:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('crop21.jpg')
blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
hsv=cv2.cvtColor(blur,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#threshold green
low_g=np.array([35,100,60],np.uint8)
up_g=np.array([85,255,190],np.uint8)
mask=cv2.inRange(hsv,low_g,up_g)
mask_upstate=cv2.bitwise_and(blur, blur, mask=mask)
#get the bgr value
mean=cv2.mean(mask_upstate)
print (mean)

cv2.imshow('image',mask_upstate)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you have a masked image with a leaf and a black background. The problem now is that it is dividing the sum of the colours by the amount of all pixels, instead of just dividing it by the amount of pixels that has the leaf. An easy quick way to solve this is by multiplying the result from the `mean = cv2.mean(mask_upstate)` by `Total pixels / Non-black pixels`, which can be done as follows:

```
# Get the BGR value
mean = cv2.mean(mask_upstate)
multiplier = float(mask.size)/cv2.countNonZero(mask)
mean = tuple([multiplier * x for x in mean])
```

Thus, you have the mean of just the non-black pixels, ergo the leaf without the black background.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I got an error cn == 1 in function cv::countNonZero. How to fix it?

Comment: Do it with te mask, not the mask_upstate, as mask is a binary image and the multiplier computation gives the same result. Just edited!